# How do I solve $\int_{C}\frac{-y\,dx+(x-1)\,dy}{(x-1)^2+y^2} $?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

If
$$\gamma=(2\cos(t)+4\cos^2(t) , 2\sin(t)+4\sin(t)\cos(t))$$

and $C$ is a path defined by $\gamma$ when $\frac{-2\pi}{3} \le t\le \frac{4\pi}{3}$.

calculate:

$$\int_{C}\frac{-y\,dx+(x-1)\,dy}{(x-1)^2+y^2} $$

first of all, I was given a hint that $\gamma$ can be changed to polar coordinates, but it seems to me already in these coordinates. am I missing something?

second, for calculating the integral I thought to use that:

$$\int_{C}f\,dr=\int_{0}^1f(\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt$$

but with current parametrization it is too messy.

any ideas how to approach this question?

edit: I draw the function using matlab:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkzFI.png

Comment: were not you given integration limits?

Comment: @M.Mass yeah sorry I added that now

Comment: see my answer now, I do not know why you put $[0;1]$ interval into your formaula, it totally depends on the nature of the task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can judge it is  the second type of line integral, while your sugested formula is used to calculate  the first one.

For second type you have the following:

$$ \begin{cases} x = 2\cos t + 4\cos^2 t \\ y = 2\sin t + 4\sin t\cos t \end{cases}$$

so first of all you have to find:

$$\begin{cases} dx =(2\cos t +4\cos^2 t)'\,dt \\ dy = (2\sin t +4\sin t\cos t)'dt \end{cases}$$

After that you have to transder your integral to the defenite one with given limits, where $x$ will be your originally given $x$ parametric coordinate, $y$ your originally given $y$ parametric coordinate and therefore $dx$ and $dy$ are both ones come from derivatives I've written above.

After all that you will have to just simplify the integral and solve it as remarkable defenite integral with limits $[\frac{-2\pi}{3};\frac{4\pi}{3}]$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I added a graph of the path. maybe i need to calculate two different line integral since it is not one-to-one?

Comment: @segevp, the way I told you works just fine, plot is not needed to complete the task (if it is not required by that).